# python merge two query sets and addition of matching records

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset, array-merge

I have a need to merge two querysets together with simalar data.

Set 1 (stats) has a list of teams, total points for that team and the division the team is in.

Set 2 (spares) has a list of teams that have had a member spare for them which includes the teams and points (no division for this set).

What I would like to do is merge the querysets into one and when the teams match, just add the spares points to the team total, keeping the team name and division.

The code i am using below will sort of do what i am looking for except it does not include the teams that never had a spare on it.

Consider the following data.

Stats List

- Team 1 : 8 Points : Division A
- Team 2 : 3 Points : Division B
- Team 3 : 7 Points : Division A
- Team 4 : 5 Points : Division B
- Team 5 : 4 Points : Division A

Spares List

- Team 1 : 3 points
- Team 3 : 6 Points

So what I want to do is merge these two lists where the teams match but total their points. In this case the final list would look like this:

Final List

- Team 1 : 11 Points : Division A
- Team 2 : 3 Points : Division B
- Team 3 : 13 Points : Division A
- Team 4 : 5 Points : Division B
- Team 5 : 4 Points : Division A

Where team 1 and 3 have new totals added from the spares list.

The code i am using now that is not working for me is close to what I want

```
full_stats = {}
for stat in stats:
    for spare in spares:
        if stat['team'] == spare['team']:
            tot_points = int(stat['points']) + int(spare['points'])
            full_stats.append([stat['team'],tot_points],stat['division'])
            break
        else:
            continue
```

`full_stats` will show me only teams that have had spares (Team 1 and 3)

If I add `full_stats.append([stat['team'],stat['points'],stat['division'])` to the else, it will duplicate the data. So it will show me 7 items. Which are the 5 original team points from the stats list and then the two new totals for team 1 and team 3.

I have know I have a logic misunderstanding here but I am unable to figure out how to get these to add and only show me the 5 teams with the duplicates from the spares list added to stats list with the team of the same name.

I am doing this in a django view and will present the results of full_stats to the template.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
jAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alan-hover answer was close to what i wanted but I did not want the second tuple there to iterate through. However, separating the for loops instead of trying to do it in a nested fashion had given me the right direction to take this in. Thanks Alan.

Here is the code change I made to make this work for me.

```
full_stats = []

for stat in stats:
    full_stats.append({'team': stat['team'],'points': stat['points']})

for stat in full_stats:
    for spare in spares:
        if stat['team'] == spare['team']:
            total_points = int(stat['points']) + int(spare['points'])
            stat['points'] = total_points
```

Comment: Good to hear.  I wanted to show the iteration/populating technique without necessarily making something that would just be copy/pasted into your code without understanding.

Comment: @AlanHoover I appreciate it. Your answer did push me in the right direction to what i was looking for so thanks for that too! Now i have two ways to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

You never put the non-spare team stats into the result dict. I recommend loading the `stats` in first then updating with the info from `spares`.  I made the points and division just a two-tuple member of the dict keyed by team.

```
full_stats = {}
for stat in stats:
    full_stats[stat['team']] = (int(stat['points'],stat['division'])
for spare in spares:
    team = spare['team']
    if team in full_stats: 
        full_stats[team] = full_stats[team(0)] + int(spare['points'])
```

should accomplish what you're after.

Comment: if i do that then i get the all results, including the spares on their own. keep in mind this is a nested for loop. So I only want it to append the match to the list when the teams in both lists match and add the two points together. Then append the remaining values that did not match.